# How can I use facebook test users to login using Facebook Login in Android App?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I need to login via facebook to my application. I am trying to use facebook test accounts, as making fake accounts is both impractical and not allowed. I've seen that people usually have email attached to their test users, while mine dont have it. Any reason why?

[image]

Comment: No, no idea why. I just created a new test user in an app of mine, and it had an email address set right away. Try the edit button, you can log into the desktop version of Facebook as that test user right from there, maybe then you can add an email address via the settings?

Comment: @CBroe nothing, I've tried that all already, I don't really understand what is happening...